# What is stored in database for Dropdown Single Select Box? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, dropdownbox

I have **the Dropdown Single Select Box "Month"** with **3 options "January", "February" and "March"** as shown below:

[image]

This is the code for **the Dropdown Single Select Box "Month"** in **"Date" class** below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
    class Months(models.TextChoices):
        JANUARY  = 'JAN', 'January'
        FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
        MARCH    = 'MAR', 'March'
    
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Months.choices)
```

And, this is the old version code for **the Dropdown Single Select Box "Month"** in **"Date" class** below which is equivalent to the above code:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
    JANUARY  = 'JAN'
    FEBRUARY = 'FEB'
    MARCH    = 'MAR'

    MANTHS = [
        (JANUARY,  'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH,    'March')
    ]

    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MANTHS)
```

Now, if I choose **"February"** and click on **"SAVE"**, what is stored in database? **"FEBRUARY"**? **"FEB"**? or **"February"**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"FEB"** is stored in database. Actually as shown below, **"FEBRUARY"** is just a variable and **"FEB"** is the value stored in DB(Database) and **"February"** is the option displayed in **the Dropdown Single Select Box "Month"** on **"Add date" page** of **Django Admin(GUI)**:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
    class Months(models.TextChoices):
     # |Variable|  | DB | | Option |
        JANUARY  = 'JAN', 'January'
        FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
        MARCH    = 'MAR', 'March'
    
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Months.choices)
```

For the old version code below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
 # |Variable|  | DB | 
    JANUARY  = 'JAN'
    FEBRUARY = 'FEB'
    MARCH    = 'MAR'

    MANTHS = [
      # |Variable| | Option |
        (JANUARY,  'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH,    'March')
    ]

    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MANTHS)
```

And as shown below, **"FEB"** is stored in database(SQLite)

[image]

In addition, by adding this code below to **"Date" class**:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.month
```

You can check what is stored in database on **"Select date to change" page** of **Django Admin(GUI)** as shown below:

[image]

This is the full code below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
    class Months(models.TextChoices):
     # |Variable|  | DB | | Option |
        JANUARY  = 'JAN', 'January'
        FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
        MARCH    = 'MAR', 'March'
    
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Months.choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.month
```

And, this is the full code for the old version below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Date(models.Model):
 # |Variable|  | DB | 
    JANUARY  = 'JAN'
    FEBRUARY = 'FEB'
    MARCH    = 'MAR'

    MANTHS = [
      # |Variable| | Option |
        (JANUARY,  'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH,    'March')
    ]

    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MANTHS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.month
```